# How to speed up magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: performance, magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I need help and advice on how to improve my magento 1.7.0.2 website perfomance as it seems to take a while to load. I need any help on how to make it load faster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Joe, you can try the follow steps:

1. Enabled magento caching
2. Enabled APC
3. MySQL Query caching
4. GZip compression of html,css,js
5. Into your PHP change php_value memory_limit 128M
6. Use NGINX and PHP-FPM instead APACHExx;

Well there are many other ways to improve magento, however those ones should help heaps!

Comment: How to do GZip compression html,css,js ?